# How to change where asset_path looks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm using a CDN and I have a CNAME for `static.example.com` pointing towards the rails `public/assets` folder.

The problem is I'm using Nginx to create that subdomain, and because it's using the assets folder as it's root, assets are now stored at:

`static.example.com/hi.jpg`

But `asset_path` wants to look in `static.example.com/assets/hi.jpg`

I don't want to change the location of where assets are compiled or anything that physically changes how the asset pipeline currently works - I only want to specify a new 'root' prefix when an asset is called upon.

Or, I was thinking of how I could use nginx to 'link' those 2 paths above, so that when they visit `/assets/hi.jpg` it would actually look in `/hi.jpg`, although I'm not sure how to do this with Nginx.

Either solution I would be okay with.. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the url path via `config.assets.prefix` and the place where assets are looked for is configured with `config.assets.paths`.

From the guide on [configuring assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-assets):

> `config.assets.paths` contains the paths which are used to look for assets. Appending paths to this configuration option will cause those paths to be used in the search for assets.
>
> `config.assets.prefix` defines the prefix where assets are served from. Defaults to /assets.

Comment: will that actually move all my compiled assets though and lump them in `public`?

Comment: There are two parts to it. This is the configuration for the url generated if I understand this right. I'll expand on my answer.

Comment: Sorry I should clarify -- I mean when it precompiles my assets and generates the files with digest filenames, is it going to put them all in /public if i change the prefix?

Comment: Based on the way serving files from the public directory works, I assume what you are asking is precisely what the prefix setting is used for. Putting the generated files into the folder with that prefix will automatically make serving them from there work. So, not 100% but at least 95%-ish sure that that configuration option will do what you want.